# 403 Error while invoking Lamda function calling S3 for ob ject retrieval

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, roles, aws-java-sdk

Most of threads on similar topic has advised creating an IAM role to be assigned to Lamda function and creating a bucket level policy in S3 console to allow access for above role.

Have created these as below

Role for my Lamda function -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmtlamda",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::referencedataepiko/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::referencedataepiko"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a policy configured at a bucket level -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::************:role/$role_name_lamda"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::referencedataepiko/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::referencedataepiko"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
Thought these would have been sufficient:) Post above configurations tried testing the Lamda from its Test tab. But still get the same error ""error": "Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied.." 

Would appreciate if i can know whats missing above.
(Note - There is no server side encryption for s3 buckets)

1 more addition to the post - I am using a Java AWS sdk for writing the Lamda function. Have tried few combinations on setting up the client object for S3. Am including this to know if this is not a problem..

    //com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Region region = com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Region.US_East_2;
//AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
//AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1).build();
Creds creds = new Creds();
AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(creds.getAWSAccessKeyId(), creds.getAWSSecretKey()))
                    .withRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
```

Comment: Can you verify your Lambda is using the role you posted? Additionally, you can go to Policy Simulator to verify the access: https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/

Comment: Yes  Brian ,the Lamda uses the said role. Also yes to policy simulator able to verify the access. Still the problem persists.

Comment: You are trying to invoke lambda function so why are you creating S3 client?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal - Invoking Lamda is not a problem. Invoking S3 from Lamda is.

Comment: Ok please read my answer for the fix

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here.

```
Creds creds = new Creds();
AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(creds.getAWSAccessKeyId(), creds.getAWSSecretKey()))
                    .withRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
```

You are creating **Creds** object and in next line using **getAWSSecretKey** and **getAWSAcccessKey** method. That might be null.

There is no need to pass accessKey and secretKey separately while creating client of any AWS service inside Lambda function. You can try this.

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                       .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                       .build();
```

Comment: For the purpose of testing, I have made the getter methods return the access key. So that a'nt null. Secondly, had tried your suggested code as a part of many permutations & combinations earlier. But that didn't work.